# How does the <glob> parameter to 'git show-branch' work?

Tags: git

The documentation for git show-branch says:

> A glob pattern that matches branch or tag names under refs/. For example, if you have many topic branches under refs/heads/topic, giving topic/* would show all of them.

I take this to mean that if I do:

```
git show-branch 10
```

I should get a list of all branches whose name contains the string '10', and if I do:

```
git show-branch 10.*.x
```

I'll get branches 10.0.x, 10.1.x, etc.

However, I get:

> fatal: bad sha1 reference 10

How does this work?

Comment: You probably don't want the glob expanded by your shell - quote it before passing it to git.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `git show-branch 10*` cause just providing `10` will make git think that you mean it *exactly*  and if there is no branch called `10` then it will end up complaining about it (trying to parse it into a commit ID as a fallback).